# javascript - One image in an array is not loading

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, preload

I'm having a bit of trouble when preloading images in an array to later be drawn on a canvas (like a 2D top-down game board). However, it seems like one of these images (Greyscale GIFs, btw) refuses to load. I know it is one because when using an example from somewhere to count down the remaining images, it stops if set to 256, but will continue if set to 255.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
var xmlDoc;
var canvas = document.getElementById("leveldraw");
var displayLevel = document.getElementById("leveldisp");
var levelList = document.getElementById("level");
var setlayer1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
var setlayer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
var setlayer3 = document.getElementById("layer3");
var setlayer4 = document.getElementById("layer4");
var setmarkings = document.getElementById("marks");
var objects = [];

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
        xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
        preloadImages()
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "levels.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

if(canvas.getContext)
{
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function preloadImages()
{
    var img;
    var remaining = 256;
    for(var i=0; i<256; i=i+1)
    {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function()
        {
            --remaining;
            document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "<b>Loading: " + parseInt((1-(remaining/256))*100) + "%</b>";
            if(remaining<=0)
            {
                ChangeLevel();
            }
        };
        img.src = "objects/img" + ("00" + i.toString(16)).slice(-2) + ".gif";
        objects.push(img);
    }
}

function ChangeLevel()
{
    document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "<b>Loading...</b>";
    var levelnumber = levelList.selectedIndex;
    var width=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("width")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var height=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("height")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var layout=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("layout")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var type=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("type")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var layer0data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("layer0")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var layer1data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("layer1")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var layer2data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("layer2")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var layer3data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("layer3")[levelnumber].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    canvas.width=width*16;
    canvas.height=height*16;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    if(layer1.checked==true)
    {
        console.log("layer1");
        var i=1;
        for(var y=0; y<height; y=y+1)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<width; x=x+1)
            {
                try {
                    ctx.drawImage(objects[parseInt(layer0data.substring(i,i+2),16)],x*16,y*16);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message + " at " + ("00" + x).slice(-2) + "x" + ("00" + y).slice(-2) + " obj:" + layer0data.substring(i,i+2));
                }
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }
    if(layer2.checked==true)
    {
        console.log("layer2");
        var i=1;
        for(var y=0; y<height; y=y+1)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<width; x=x+1)
            {
                try {
                    ctx.drawImage(objects[parseInt(layer1data.substring(i,i+2),16)],x*16,y*16);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message + " at " + ("00" + x).slice(-2) + "x" + ("00" + y).slice(-2) + " obj:" + layer1data.substring(i,i+2));
                }
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }
    if(layer3.checked==true)
    {
        console.log("layer3");
        var i=1;
        for(var y=0; y<height; y=y+1)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<width; x=x+1)
            {
                try {
                    ctx.drawImage(objects[parseInt(layer2data.substring(i,i+2),16)],x*16,y*16);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message + " at " + ("00" + x).slice(-2) + "x" + ("00" + y).slice(-2) + " obj:" + layer2data.substring(i,i+2));
                }
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }
    if(layer4.checked==true)
    {
        console.log("layer4");
        var i=1;
        for(var y=0; y<height; y=y+1)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<width; x=x+1)
            {
                try {
                    ctx.drawImage(objects[parseInt(layer3data.substring(i,i+2),16)],x*16,y*16);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message + " at " + ("00" + x).slice(-2) + "x" + ("00" + y).slice(-2) + " obj:" + layer3data.substring(i,i+2));
                }
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Been reuploading the same GIF over and over ([imgad.gif](http://www.edwardleuf.org/MadMartin/thriller/objects/imgad.gif)).

Comment: You never decrement `remaining` anywhere? As far as I can see, `if(remaining<=0)` will never be true.

Comment: @JohannesJander If that were true, then why does it stop at 99%? Why did it complete if I set `remaining = 255`?

Comment: Different code I suspect. There is no way short of a miracle that `ChangeLevel()` is getting called here. That may not be your problem because the images are loaded via `i`, I just wanted to point out your code has more issues than you are aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the image file name is `imgad.gif`, most AdBlockers block it, because of the `ad` part.... Renaming the image should solve it.

Comment: `img00.gif` does exist. It is loaded when `var i=0`, but `i` never reaches `256`. I also moved `remaining` to the outside, but that didn't seem to help. When I set `remaining = 255` it then loads, BUT that one `imgad.gif` is missing from the "level".

Comment: But then `img00.gif` is loaded twice, instead of the other image, because the 256th image (as I described) will result in the file name (src) `img00.gif`

Comment: I might have found a solution: imgad.gif is blocked by your browser? (In my case Chrome gives the `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error in the console.) Because of the name 'ad' which might be falsely interpreted by a AdBlocker

Comment: If I manually disable my Adblocker, the preload script works fine with the adjustments mentioned above: https://jsfiddle.net/qmq072cg/

Comment: So, what you are telling me is that `for( i = 0; while i is LESS THAN 256; increment i )` will continue beyond 255 no matter what? No matter if it is `Less Than <` or `Less Than Or Equal to <=` or any other operator? And that was silly that the Hexadecimal number gets caught by Adblock. The project started off as PHP so all hex numbers were fine. Seems like I'll have to rename all images to standard decimals.

Comment: I misread the script, the decrement is before the onload function, so that should be alright. But still, if you need more images, this will become a problem.

Comment: Well aware of the number of numbers. Because there were only 256 "sprites" I didn't think more on that. Thanks for the heads up on the ADblock part.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** Never use hexadecimals because the number AD can be blocked by Adblockers.

Thanks to Philip for discovering that.